# Multiple copy of view in scrollview

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uiview, uiscrollview

I have 2 views with some Lables & textfields in nib files. I want to make multiple copy of the view and add in a scrollview. When i start adding the view in the scrollview, it is added at the top of the scrollview. Help would be appreciated. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: could you explain the scenario in detail? actually its really hard to understand what you actually wants and what is currently that you are facing...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the views to be added one after another, you must calculate the height of your view and modify the frame of each new view being added to the scroll. If, for example, your view is 100px height, then you must add it like this:

```
// Number of views added to the scroll
NSUInteger numberOfViews = 0;

// View loaded from XIB
theNewView.frame = CGRectMake(theNewView.frame.origin.x, 
                              theNewView.frame.origin.y + numberOfViews*theNewView.frame.size.height,
                              theNewView.frame.size.width,
                              theNewView.frame.size.height);


// Add the view to the scroll and increment the number of views
[scrollView addSubview:theNewView];
numberOfViews++;
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to set frame of the views you are adding to the scrollView.

```
subview.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 200);
[self addSubView:c];
```

`CGRectMake` defines where to add the subview to the view.

```
CGRectMake(CGFloat x, CGFloat y, CGFloat width, CGFloat height );
```

Doing this will prevent the views being added in scrollView to be on top of each other.

Comment: My Views are a seperate object in the nib file. I want to add this object to a particular location in scrollView. My Problem is all my views are being added to origin of the scrollview.

Comment: yes thats what i am saying. You must be having reference to those views in your code?So you can use `CGRectMake` to set the frame or you can use XCode Interface Builder itself to set the location of the views.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you need these methods?

```
-sendSubviewToBack:
–bringSubviewToFront:
```